# Enviando informações do Ajax para Controller

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax, codeigniter

Bom dia galera, tudo beleza?

Estou fazendo uma aplicação onde meu select vai operar o que vai aparecer na minha página. Estou usando o CodeIgniter, então a escolha do select vai para um controller. Preciso que minha pagina não dê refresh!

Estou usando Ajax para tentar contornar está situação, porém minha primeira visita a ele foi ontem, sou muito leigo ainda.

O que acontece é:

Quero pegar o value do select -> jogar esse value no controller -> e trazer os dados da verificação da minha Query no db para view.

Html:

```html
 <form real="form" id="User" nome="form" method="post" action='<?= base_url("index.php/welcome");?>'>
                  <select class="form-control" name="selectUser" id="seletor">
                     <option  value='<?= $_SESSION["nome"]?>' >Only me</option>
                     <option  value="" >Team</option>
                  </select>
                  </form>
```

Controller:

```html
public function index()
 { 
  
  $nome = $this->input->post('selectUser');
  echo $nome;
  $this->load->model('testemodel');

  $verifica= $this->testemodel->verifica($nome);

  $data['nomecliente'] = $verifica['nome_cliente'];
  $data['horatotal'] = $verifica['hora_total'];
  $data['atividade'] = $verifica['nome_atividade'];
  
 
  
 

  $this->load->view('test', $data);
  
  
 }
```

Ajax:

```js
(function () {
    document.getElementById('seletor').addEventListener('change', function() {
        var selectedOption = this.children[this.selectedIndex];

        var value = this.value;
        
        $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "http://localhost/Time/index.php/welcome/index",
    data: value,
    dataType: 'json',
    
    
        });
       
       
    })
})();
```

Agradeço a vocês por qualquer norte!

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com o meu novo entendimento da resposta você precisa que ao alterar a `option` de um `select`, o `value` da `option` seja enviada para seu controller. Caso eu esteja errado me corrija.

Exemplo:

```
<body>
    <select class="form-control" name="selectUser" id="seletor">
        <option  value='<?= $_SESSION["nome"]?>' >Only me</option>
    </select>

    <script>
        $("#seletor").change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "LINK_PARA_O_CONTROLLER",
                data: {"seletor": $("#seletor").val()},
                success: function(data){

                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log("Erro na requisição")
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97294/discussion-on-answer-by-vinicius-de-jesus-enviando-informacoes-do-ajax-para-cont)